# node js websocket requires c++

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2008, websocket

I want to install:

```
npm install websocket
```

and I get the message:

```
Native code compile failed!!
On Windoes, native extensions require Visual Studio and Python
```

Then I installed Visual Studio 8 and Python, but I still get the message.
How can Visual Studio compile the code?

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/websocket states this must be Python 2.7 and not 3.x.  Which version did you install?

Comment: visual-cpp-express 2010 and python 2.7   ...now it works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you installing correct versions of them. From the websocket npm [page](https://npmjs.org/package/websocket) :

> **Note for Windows Users**
>
> Because there is a small C++ component used for validating UTF-8 data,
>   you will need to install a few other software packages in addition to
>   Node to be able to build this module:

- [Microsoft Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)
- [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/) (NOT Python 3.x)

Software to be installed are visual-cpp-express 2010 and python 2.7

Comment: visual-cpp-express 2010, now it works! visualstudio 2008 did not... thank you, very much!